# Reliability of desktop with no grounding

Tags: power-supply

So, the outlet I plug my computer on has no grounding. I always assumed that this was "just" a safety concern: unless some fault in the PSU connects line to ground/chassis, nothing bad should happen - and even then, it should only scare the human touching the PC, not hurt my precious motherboard. However, 4 failed PSUs (two of which took my motherboard with them) in 10 years make me question these assumptions.

So my question is: is there any way the lack of grounding can affect the durability of a desktop PC? Or am I just unlucky?

(I can only think of an ungrounded PC being more susceptible to ESD, but this does not appear to be the case: I live in a very high humidity area - average 78%, all time low 39% - and have absolutely never experienced ESD)

Comment: Grounding depends on how the psu is designed. However, everything in a pc uses it for a reference. Without a ground connection, your ground is floating, and this had serious implications for computers which assume a very, very steady supply.

Comment: Its worth noting that things like spark gaps discharge to ground, without a ground connection the excess charge may buildup and still harm the circuit. It's hard to say more without knowing the circuits in question. However, generally, if a circuit is designed with a ground connection, use a ground connection.

Comment: Just to be clear: I'm not neglecting the ground connection because I think I know better: my house's wiring is nuts, and I'm pretty sure the few grounded outlets that I eventually find are actually just connected to a spliced neutral. I'm doing this because it would be too costly to do it right.

Comment: If you don't do it right, then you should expect problems.

Comment: Spend the money and save yours or anothers life. Ground connections and importantly Residual Current Device's  (RCD) provide a vital saftey feature. The "scare" you refer to is just dumb luck that the current was either not high enough or did not pass through the heart on its way to ground.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of no good reason for the lack of a true earth ground to have any effect on the internals of the isolated computer itself. However, any time your computer is hardwired to any peripheral device with its own power supply and is expected to share a ground connection - here a monitor is a good example - you run some risks because of the floating and nonshared ground reference between the computer and the peripheral.

If nothing else... if you cannot establish a true earth ground... then at the very least build a simple outlet box on the end of a short extension cord and use it to tie all the ground plugs' ground references together.

Outside the point at hand: laptops are another type of animal altogether, since they operate entirely without any ground reference.

Comment: That's a precaution I hadn't thought of, thanks! I don't think this was what happened though, since I believe this sort of problem would have fried the motherboard but not the PSU.

Comment: I've seen some pretty freaky stuff happen inside a desktop... especially back in the old days when RS-232 was common. Worse was long-run RS-422, when some foo' connected the ground at both ends of the shield... to entirely different isolated grounds, causing some nasty ground loops! But... yeah, there's not any truly good reason for the power supply to require an earth ground; it supplies its own ground reference for everything it does, and never refers to earth ground.

Comment: What about spark gaps, MOV's, and other ESD and high voltage transients? The power supply might be isolated via a transformer, but the excessive charge in the above cases must be shunted somewhere. Just because it's isolated doesn't mean it doesn't have a need for a ground connection.

Comment: Tying the ground references together seems like a very bad idea to me. If you do tie it to local neutral, current flow will raise the ground above true neutral creating a shock hazard. If you don't tie it to local ground, isolation components between hot and ground will leak current that may have nowhere to go but a person touching the computer.